# Why assets served as compiled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sprockets, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am using Rails 5.2, and I notice when serving a page, the javascript file being served is compiled, however, I am in development mode.

for example, I get this html:

```
<script src="/assets/auth0/auth0_dialog.self-73034e01a7da3c346f6c123d6890950c4f1aac7f5f35ca09ced526e9c550328d.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/auth0/lock_init.self-b564b1f75c18a2fbbe1d41be6af70aa3d1c36c31aeb50cf52017d2ec31ceba10.js?body=1"></script>
```

for:

```
= javascript_include_tag "auth0/auth0_dialog"
= javascript_include_tag "auth0/lock_init"
```

any idea?

Comment: Did you have the option `config.assets.debug = true` in your `development.rb` file?

Comment: yes, I tried setting true and tried false, same result

Comment: Try <%= javascript_include_tag "application", debug: true %> to be sure. Maybe your dev server is running in production.  Also, what's your dev config for config.assets.compile?

Comment: I just tried `rails tmp:cache:clear` and it worked fine, it seems that it assets were cached!